# How to upload a file with SFTP (Renci.schNet)

Tags: .net, wordpress, sftp

I'm using Renci.schNet 2020.0.1.0 to upload a file to a Wordpress site using SFTP

The credentals work in Filezilla but when I try with SftpClient I get a 1006 error...
"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

Any idea why it works in Filezilla and not in SftpClient?

**Many thanks for the reply**

Unfortunately I don't own the Wordpress site so I can't provide a reproducable example. However, here is the redacted Filezilla log, my code and the detail of the error message.

```
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Status: Resolving address of XXXXXXXXX.co.uk
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Status: Connecting to 35.214.68.233:21...
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Response: 220-##########################################################
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Response: 220-Please upload your web files to the public_html directory.
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Response: 220-Note that letters are case sensitive.
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Response: 220-##########################################################
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Response: 220 This is a private system - No anonymous login
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Command: AUTH TLS
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Response: 234 AUTH TLS OK.
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Status: Initializing TLS...
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Status: Verifying certificate...
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Status: TLS connection established.
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Command: USER YYYY
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Response: 331 User XXXXXXXXX OK. Password required
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Command: PASS **********
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Response: 230-Your bandwidth usage is restricted
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Response: 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
2021-12-19 10:28:35 3284 1 Command: SYST
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response: 215 UNIX Type: L8
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Command: FEAT
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response: 211-Extensions supported:
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  UTF8
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  EPRT
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  IDLE
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  MDTM
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  SIZE
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  MFMT
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  REST STREAM
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  MLST type*;size*;sizd*;modify*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.uid*;UNIX.gid*;unique*;
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  MLSD
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  PRET
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  AUTH TLS
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  PBSZ
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  PROT
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  TVFS
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  ESTA
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  PASV
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  EPSV
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response:  ESTP
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response: 211 End.
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response: 504 Unknown command
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Command: PBSZ 0
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response: 200 PBSZ=0
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Command: PROT P
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response: 200 Data protection level set to "private"
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Status: Logged in
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Command: PWD
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response: 257 "/" is your current location
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Command: TYPE I
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Command: PASV
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (35,214,68,233,135,202)
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Command: MLSD
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response: 150 Accepted data connection
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Response: 226 3 matches total
2021-12-19 10:28:36 3284 1 Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
2021-12-19 10:28:38 3284 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/XXXXXXXXX.co.uk"...
2021-12-19 10:28:38 3284 1 Command: CWD XXXXXXXXX.co.uk
2021-12-19 10:28:38 3284 1 Response: 250 OK. Current directory is /XXXXXXXXX.co.uk
2021-12-19 10:28:38 3284 1 Command: PWD
2021-12-19 10:28:39 3284 1 Response: 257 "/XXXXXXXXX.co.uk" is your current location
2021-12-19 10:28:39 3284 1 Command: PASV
2021-12-19 10:28:39 3284 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (35,214,68,233,135,31)
2021-12-19 10:28:39 3284 1 Command: MLSD
2021-12-19 10:28:39 3284 1 Response: 150 Accepted data connection
2021-12-19 10:28:39 3284 1 Response: 226 5 matches total
2021-12-19 10:28:39 3284 1 Status: Directory listing of "/XXXXXXXXX.co.uk" successful
2021-12-19 10:28:43 3284 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/XXXXXXXXX.co.uk/public_html"...
2021-12-19 10:28:43 3284 1 Command: CWD public_html
2021-12-19 10:28:43 3284 1 Response: 250 OK. Current directory is /XXXXXXXXX.co.uk/public_html
2021-12-19 10:28:43 3284 1 Command: PWD
2021-12-19 10:28:43 3284 1 Response: 257 "/XXXXXXXXX.co.uk/public_html" is your current location
2021-12-19 10:28:43 3284 1 Command: PASV
2021-12-19 10:28:43 3284 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (35,214,68,233,135,129)
2021-12-19 10:28:43 3284 1 Command: MLSD
2021-12-19 10:28:43 3284 1 Response: 150 Accepted data connection
2021-12-19 10:28:43 3284 1 Response: 226 26 matches total
2021-12-19 10:28:43 3284 1 Status: Directory listing of "/XXXXXXXXX.co.uk/public_html" successful
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Status: Resolving address of XXXXXXXXX.co.uk
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Status: Connecting to 35.214.68.233:21...
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Response: 220-##########################################################
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Response: 220-Please upload your web files to the public_html directory.
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Response: 220-Note that letters are case sensitive.
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Response: 220-##########################################################
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Response: 220 This is a private system - No anonymous login
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Command: AUTH TLS
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Response: 234 AUTH TLS OK.
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Status: Initializing TLS...
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Status: Verifying certificate...
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Status: TLS connection established.
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Command: USER YYYY
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Response: 331 User YYYY OK. Password required
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Command: PASS **********
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Response: 230-Your bandwidth usage is restricted
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Response: 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
2021-12-19 10:28:46 3284 3 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Response: 504 Unknown command
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Command: PBSZ 0
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Response: 200 PBSZ=0
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Command: PROT P
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Response: 200 Data protection level set to "private"
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Status: Logged in
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Status: Starting upload of I:\Documents\Development\PCS\PCS_WebApp\PCS_WebApp\PCS_Data\SIE\SIE 2022-210303163700\status.html
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Command: CWD /XXXXXXXXX.co.uk/public_html
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Response: 250 OK. Current directory is /XXXXXXXXX.co.uk/public_html
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Command: PWD
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Response: 257 "/XXXXXXXXX.co.uk/public_html" is your current location
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Command: TYPE A
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Response: 200 TYPE is now ASCII
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Command: PASV
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (35,214,68,233,135,157)
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Command: STOR status.html
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Response: 150 Accepted data connection
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Response: 226-Warning: client is in ASCII mode - Assuming data is plain text
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Response: 226-File successfully transferred
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Response: 226 0.008 seconds (measured here), 355.68 Kbytes per second
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Status: File transfer successful, transferred 3,055 bytes in 1 second
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/XXXXXXXXX.co.uk/public_html"...
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Command: TYPE I
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Response: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Command: PASV
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (35,214,68,233,135,206)
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Command: MLSD
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Response: 150 Accepted data connection
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Response: 226 27 matches total
2021-12-19 10:28:47 3284 3 Status: Directory listing of "/XXXXXXXXX.co.uk/public_html" successful
```

Code ....

```
Friend Function sftpUploadFile(server As String, loginName As String, password As String, filePath As String, ftpPath As String) As Boolean
        Dim sftp = New SftpClient(server, loginName, password)
        Using sftp
            Try
                Debug.WriteLine("start connect " & Now)
                sftp.Connect()
                Debug.WriteLine("end connect " & Now)
                Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)
                Using fs
                    sftp.BufferSize = 4 * 1024
                    sftp.UploadFile(fs, ftpPath)
                End Using
                sftp.Disconnect()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error in sftp - " & ex.Message & vbCr & "Uploading " & filePath & " to " & ftpPath, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, appTitle)
                Debug.WriteLine("exception raised " & Now)
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                Debug.WriteLine("server=" & server & " Login=" & loginName & " pwd=" & password)
                Debug.WriteLine("from=" & filePath & " to=" & ftpPath)
                Return False
            End Try
        End Using
        Return True
    End Function
```

Debug output.....

```
start connect 19/12/2021 10:47:51
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Renci.SshNet.dll
exception raised 19/12/2021 10:49:07
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
server=XXXXXXXXX.co.uk Login=YYYY pwd=*******
from=I:\Documents\Development\PCS\PCS_WebApp\PCS_WebApp\PCS_Data\SIE\SIE 2022-210303163700\status.html to=XXXXXXXXX.co.uk/public_html/pcsstatus.html
```

---

I've now installed the FluentFTP package and changed the code to

```
Dim sftp = New FtpClient(server, loginName, password)
        Using sftp
            Try
                Debug.WriteLine("start connect " & Now)
                sftp.EncryptionMode = FtpEncryptionMode.Explicit
                sftp.ValidateAnyCertificate = True
                sftp.Connect()
                Debug.WriteLine("end connect " & Now)
                sftp.UploadFile(filePath, ftpPath, FtpRemoteExists.Overwrite = True)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.WriteLine("exception raised " & Now)
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                Debug.WriteLine("server=" & server & " Login=" & loginName & " pwd=" & password)
                Debug.WriteLine("from=" & filePath & " to=" & ftpPath)
                Return False
            End Try
        End Using
```

I now get as far as authorising but the remote site shts down the connection

```
start connect 20/12/2021 14:09:05

# Connect()
Status:   Connecting to 35.214.68.233:21
Response: 220-##########################################################
Response: 220-Please upload your web files to the public_html directory.
Response: 220-Note that letters are case sensitive.
Response: 220-##########################################################
Response: 220 This is a private system - No anonymous login
Command:  AUTH TLS
Response: 234 AUTH TLS OK.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in FluentFTP.dll
exception raised 20/12/2021 14:09:05
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
server=XXXXXXX.co.uk Login=YYYY pwd=**********
from=I:\Documents\Development\PCS\PCS_WebApp\PCS_WebApp\PCS_Data\SIE\SIE 2022-210303163700\status.html to=XXXXXXX.co.uk/public_html/pcsstatus.html
```

Comment: Sounds a little like [SSH.NET timeout when connecting to AWS Managed SFTP server in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54014749/205233) but since you are on v2020.0.1.0 this specific issue should be fixed for you.

Comment: We need [mcve]. + Verbose FileZilla log from file the *same* machine that runs your SSH.NET code will be useful too.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don;t won the wordpress site, so I can;t provide a reproducable example.

Comment: Based on your most recent additions...  FileZilla isn't connecting via SFTP - it's connecting via FTPS.

Comment: I've changed to FTPS and added to my original post, but I now get a different error - I'd really appreciate more help